# MySQL limit range

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

```
SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The query above will return the first 10 ranks.

How to modify the `LIMIT`, or maybe is there another syntax to query the 10th rank through the 20th rank?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You should use:

```
SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10,10;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

The two arguments 10,10 are (Offset, Limit) so this will retrieve rows 11-20.
9,11 Would be required to grab the 10th - 20th rank.

Answer (score 24):

Use `offset` to clarify the query.

```
SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: OFFSET is definitely a better idea when you have to construct query in the code.

Answer (score 6):

Limit has also an offset parameter

```
SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10,10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT rank, name, score
FROM (
    SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank, name, score
    FROM mydb
    ORDER BY score DESC 
    LIMIT 100 
) X
WHERE rank >= 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use **offset**

```
SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

here, **offset** indicates that from where next 10 data will show.
you may also use below :

```
SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10, 10
```

Comment: Please [don't provide a solution that is already covered by another answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/192293/269535). If you agree with another answer, then when you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you may [upvote it](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up), which is the Stack Overflow way of indicating your agreement. See also [answer].