# findAll() method to return records between 2 line numbers

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot/Data/MVC. I need to use my Spring Data repository `myEntitiyRepository` to find all records from line number X to line number Y. So the method will maybe look something like this:

```
@Query(...)
myEntityRepository.findall(@Param("x") String startLine, @Param("y") String endLine);
```

So that I can use it in my `@Controller` and give the user the possibility of selecting rows between 2 numbers of his choosing.

Comment: What does "line number" mean in the context of your problem? Are you trying to have it represent a row within the table that the data is stored in?

Comment: I explained better in a comment bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a stab at the fact that your "line number" really means the rows in the result of the query. If that is the case then you would want to look at [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts). With that you can do something like:

```
Page<User> users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 20));
```

Where 1 is the second page (0 index for pages) and you are specifying the page size of 20 items. As such this specific example would get the 21st to 40th result from the findAll().

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. For example if I have 10 records in my user table, I need a Spring Data method which can allow me to enter 2 params. the first defines the start line and the second the end line. So if I choose number 3 & 8, the method will return a list of records beginning from the 3rd record to the 8th record. So at the end I'll use it in a controller @RequestMapping method to let the user choose those 2 numbers.

Comment: The concept is the same... You are using LIMIT and OFFSET within the SQL query although it is MySQL specific and if you are trying to program to be implementation agnostic you should try to leverage the PagingAndSortingRepository.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767479/mysql-limit-range

If you want to make a custom query it would look like:

`@Query("SELECT e FROM entity LIMIT ?2 - ?1 OFFSET ?1")
public List<Entity> findallBetweenRange(String startLine, String endLine)`